# Knockout JS and radio button not binding on first click

Tags: knockout.js

I am working on a thin client using knockout JS and am having some issues with the radio button and am hoping someone here might be able to lend some insight into what maybe causing this and what I can do to rectify the situation.

I have a fairly typical layout for an array of radio buttons.

```
<p data-bind="text: background().description"></p>
<div data-bind="foreach: backgroundOptions" class="bg-options">
    <p data-bind="text: description" class="color-swatch"></p>
    <input type="radio" name="backgroundsGroup" data-bind="checked: $parent.backgroundId, value:id"/>
</div>​
```

You can see I am binding to the backgroundId for the parent object.

The JS for the parent object and object being displayed looks as follows:

```
var CardBackground = function(imagePath, swatchPath, id, description) {
    var self = this;

    var _imagePath = imagePath;
    self.imagePath = ko.observable(_imagePath);

    var _id = id;
    self.id = ko.observable(_id);

    var _description = description;
    self.description = ko.observable(_description);

    var _swatch = swatchPath;
    self.swatchPath = ko.observable(_swatch);
};

var Card = function() {
    var self = this;
    getBackgrounds = function() {
        var bgs = [
            new CardBackground("noCardLarge.jpg", "card_swatch-blue.jpg", -1, "None Selected"),
            new CardBackground("greenCard.jpg", "card_swatch-green.jpg", 10, "Green Contour Card"),
            new CardBackground("purpleCard.jpg", "card_swatch-purple.jpg", 11, "Purple Contour Card"),
            new CardBackground("redCard.jpg", "card_swatch-red.jpg", 12, "Red Contour Card"),
            new CardBackground("whiteCard.jpg", "card_swatch-white.jpg", 13, "White Contour Card"),
            new CardBackground("yellowCard.jpg", "card_swatch-yellow.jpg", 14, "Yellow Contour Card")
            ];
        return bgs;
    }
    self.backgroundOptions = getBackgrounds();

    var _defaultBackground = self.backgroundOptions[0];
    self.defaultBackground = ko.observable(_defaultBackground);

    var _background = self.defaultBackground();
    self.background = ko.observable(_background);

    self.backgroundId = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var values = self.backgroundOptions;
            return values.length ? values[0] : [];
        },

        write: function(newValue) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.backgroundOptions.length; i++) {
                if (self.backgroundOptions[i].id() == newValue) {
                    self.background(self.backgroundOptions[i]);
                    return;
                }
            }
        },
        owner: this
    });
};
```

Right now it takes two clicks to get the binding to take action initially, then its just one click from that point forward.

Additionally even though a default value is set the respective option box is not selected.    If you change the index on the default background the description above is correct, but the radio button is not correct.

I have created an example of this.
http://jsfiddle.net/JS2GV/2/

any insight someone might have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get it to have the defaultBackground selected on initial bind change self.backgroudId's read to...

```
return _background.id();
```

so the checked binding will get the id of the 'selected' background, then switch the order of the radio input's binding to...

```
"value:id, checked: $parent.backgroundId"
```

so the value binding will assign a value to the input which is required to make the checked binding work correctly.

Regarding the double clicking required to get the option to change, it's due to the fact that the id's in the ViewModel are integers while the value's in the generated radio Inputs are represented as strings. To fix wrap all of the id's in your view model in quotes so they are strings.

Here's an updated jsfiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/JS2GV/11/

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I changed my integers to strings, and the binding is working as expected.  I made a slight tweak to the read value on the binding to return self.background().id() rather than the local variable.

Comment: Mark as answered then please.

Comment: +1 for the double clicking solution. A quick .toString() and it's single clicking as expected.